# How to vertically align text to the center of the box?

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, flexbox

In safari, i can't make the text move to the middle of the box.
Its always on the top. How do i make the text stay in the middle of the box?

here is my code i'm working on:
http://jsfiddle.net/cyberjo50/B62XX/

```
#menu {
clear: both;
height: auto;
font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
font-size: 1em;
/*padding:10px;*/
margin: 5px;
display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
display: -moz-box;    /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
-webkit-flex-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400px;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
}

#menu a:link {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom:auto;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
background-color: yellow;
/*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
margin:5px;
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #1689D6;
font-size: 85%;
/*start the fix here*/
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
-ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
flex: 1 1 auto;
-webkit-align-self: auto;
-ms-flex-item-align: auto;
align-self: auto;
}
#menu a:visited {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom:auto;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
background-color: yellow;
/*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
margin:5px;
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #1689D6;
font-size: 85%;
/*start the fix here*/
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
-ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
flex: 1 1 auto;
-webkit-align-self: auto;
-ms-flex-item-align: auto;
align-self: auto;
}
#menu a:hover {
display: block;
color: #fff;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom:auto;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
background-color: red;
/*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
margin:5px;
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 85%;
/*start the fix here*/
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
-ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
flex: 1 1 auto;
-webkit-align-self: auto;
-ms-flex-item-align: auto;
align-self: auto;
}
#menu a:active {
display:block;
color: #fff;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom:auto;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
background-color: red;
/*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
margin:5px;
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 85%;
/*start the fix here*/
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
-ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
flex: 1 1 auto;
-webkit-align-self: auto;
-ms-flex-item-align: auto;
align-self: auto;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to minimize your code to only the parts relevant to your question. :-)

Comment: ok i just removed 24 lines of css code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in css for `#menu` and play further with numbers and tweaking:

```
text-align:center; line-height:50px;
```